# ¿Cómo puedo agrandar de tamaño de un div hasta rellenar el resto del espacio disponible del div en el que se ubica?

Tags: html, css

Quisiera saber cómo puedo rellenar el espacio restante de un *div* con otro *div*. Para que se entienda mejor adjunto el código

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.div1 {
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#div2 {
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#div3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 5em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="div1">
    <div id="div2">lorem5</div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Quiero que el `.div2` ocupe el resto del espacio restante; el total ocupa `100vh`. No sé cómo, a pesar de colocarle medidas al `.div1`, hacer que el `.div2` ocupe el resto del espacio restante.

Comment: Yo no termino de entender tu problema ¿puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: Hola @Josué. El espacio restante al que te refieres, ¿es horizontal o vertical? Y lo otro es si, ¿te refieres como espacio restante al espacio que no ocupa el primer elemento?

Comment: exactamente david me refiero al espacio restante que no ocupa el div1. Para explicarlo mejor lo dire asi

Div tiene 100 vh
  div1 posee 20vh
  div2 no tiene altura definida pero quiero un comando que rellene la altura de lo restante, en este ejemplo por ende lo restante seria 80vh.

Comment: Hola @JosueQuichca, revisa la publicación. Si tienes alguna duda, coméntela.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código presenta algunas lógicas equivocadas.

El siguiente código va a establecer altura y ancho a todos los div y obviamente no es lo que buscas hacer.

```
div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Lo recomendable es lo siguiente:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20%;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: brown;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">lorem5</div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Como puedes ver también utilizo el `id` en lugar de las clases, ya que las clases se usan solo en caso de que el estilo que aplicas se vaya a repetir en otros elementos.

Una vez aclarado este punto, el resto de la respuesta depende de lo que buscas hacer, cosa que aun no has especificado.

> Luego de que actualices tu pregunta con más información adaptaré mi respuesta para que sea más completa.

Comment: Lo que busco es como rellenar el height de un div exactamente con el espacio restante que queda en donde esta ubicado, el primer div que vale 100vh icluye un div de 2em de height, sobrara un aproximado de 94vh tanteando, quisiera saber que comando poner para que el 2do div ocupe todo ese espacio restante porque la idea no es tantear.

Comment: Hola, si lo ejecute, sin embargo no sale lo que busco, para ser mas claro lo que quiero lo dire con el siguiente ejemplo
<div>
  <div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">  
</div>
CSS
div vale 100vh
  div1 vale 20vh
  div2 quiero que valga el espacio restante del div que pertenece (osea en este caso sería 80vh, pero yo no se cuanto valdría en un ejemplo real)

a eso me reifiero

Comment: Entiendo, gracias ya vi el código que actualizo, pero ¿y si el primer div tiene 60px? ¿Cómo rellenar el espacio restante del siguiente div? Ya actualice mi código para q se vea mejor, pero ya entendió a lo que me refiero jeje

Answer (score 0):

> **Nota:** ejecute el código acá. Luego cópielo y modifíquelo para adaptarlo a las necesidades de su proyecto. Sin embargo, lea primero toda la explicación.

Podrías utilizar cajas flexibles, de manera que, si la altura del primer elemento varía, la del segundo elemento se adaptará automáticamente.

Esto se puede conseguir utilizando dos propiedades CSS las cuales serían:

- **[`flex-grow`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)** En español, se traduciría *crecimiento flexible* que consiste en darle la anchura o altura al elemento en función de su eje horizontal o vertical.
- **[`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink):** En español sería equivalente a decir *encogimiento flexible*. Esto permitiría reducir de tamaño al elemento donde se aplique cuando ya no cuente con espacios suficientes.

En esta solución utilizaremos la metodología [*Bloque, Elemento, Modificador* (*BEM*, por sus siglas en inglés)](https://en.bem.info/methodology/) para darle solución al siguiente problema planteado:

> Quiero que el `.div2` ocupe el resto del espacio restante, el total ocupa `100vh`, no sé cómo a pesar de colocarle medidas al `.div1`, el `.div2` ocupe el resto del espacio restante.

Solución pasaría por el siguiente fragmento. Pruébelo y siga leyendo:

```css
/* Reseteando los estilos por defecto */

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Estilos que nos interesa utilizando la metodología
   BEM */


/* Elemento contenedor */

.div {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* Estas serías las propiedades comunes */

.div__inner {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}


/* Estos son los modificadores */

.div__inner--1 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background-color: #0080d4;
}

.div__inner--2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #f06600;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <div class="div__inner div__inner--1">Cualquier texto</div>
  <div class="div__inner div__inner--2">Contenido del segundo <code>div</code></div>
</div>
```

La ventaja de la solución anterior es que no importa qué tamaño (en altura) tenga el primer elemento, el segundo siempre se adaptará a la altura disponible.

### Explicación

#### Metología BEM

Antes de explicar el código vamos a explicar brevemente la metodología *BEM*. La metodología *BEN* consiste en lo siguiente:

- *Bloque*. Es el contenedor principal de los elementos contenidos en él. De hecho, el bloque puede tener un modificador: `.bloque--modificador`.
- *Elemento*. Es el elemento que se encuentra anidado dentro del bloque, es decir: `.bloque__elemento`.
- *Modificador*. Consiste en modificar algunas propiedades de los *elementos* o *bloques*. La modificación también puede consistir agregar algunas propiedades no definidas en el *bloque* o *elemento*.

Por ejemplo:

```css
.bloque__elemento {
  /* Algunas propiedades comunes */
}

.bloque__elemento--modificador {
  /* Algunas propiedades en ambos elementos */
}
```

Lo anterior es una explicación superficial de la metodología *BEM* que utilizamos en esta publicación. Puede consultar [BEM, documentación de la metodología (en inglés)](https://en.bem.info/methodology/) para conocer como funciona.

#### Explicación de las reglas CSS utilizadas

Al elemento *bloque* o contenedor principal:

```css
.div {
  ...

  /* La parte que nos interesa */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

La hemos definido como contenedor de cajas flexibles (`display: flex`) y su eje vertical (`flex-direction: column`). Además, de una altura de `100vh`.

En ella tendremos dos elementos, que hemos definido así:

```css
.div__inner {
  /* La propiedad que nos interesa */
  flex-shrink: 1;

  /* Estas propiedades son decorativas y nada tiene que ver
     con lo que queremos conseguir. */
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

De acuerdo con la metodología *BEM* `.div__inner {}` es un elemento de bloque, significa que allí colocaremos las propopiedades comunes en ambos `divs`.

Luego, tenemos los modificadores para los `divs` que nos interesa:

```css
.div__inner--1 {
  /* La propiedad que nos interesa, le indicamos o no si 
     el elemento crecerá (ocupará espacio disponible) o no */
  flex-grow: 0;

  /* Esto es simplemente para decorar o marcar el div */
  background-color: #0080d4;
}

.div__inner--2 {
  /* Con un valor establecido a 1 le indicamos que ocupe todo 
     el espacio disponible */
  flex-grow: 1;

  /* Esto es simplemente para decorar o marcar el div */
  background-color: #f06600;
}
```

Note que `.div__inner` tienen los modificadores `--1` y `--2`, que representan los `div1` y `div2` respectivamente.

En el primer *div* (`.div__inner--1`) hemos establecido el valor de la propiedad `flex-grow` a `0` para indicarle que no ocupe todo el espacio disponible. Puedes cambiarle el tamaño si lo desea, pero no ocupará el espacio disponible.

Para el segundo *div* (`.div__inner--2`) hemos establecido el valor de la propiedad `flex-grow` a `1` para indicarle que ocupe todo el espacio disponible y se adapte al tamaño del primer *div* (`.div__inner--1`) en este caso.

Si desea profundizar sobre este tema, puede consultar:

- [Usando las cajas flexibles CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS) del sitio Web oficial de Mozilla.
- O también [Una guía completa de Flexbox (en inglés)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), una guía muy completa que lo llevará a entender cómo funciona.

> **Nota importante:** copie el código, pruébelo y modifíquelo para adaptarlo a las necesidades de su proyecto.